# Python 3 Average Answer Function integers not iterable

Tags: python

I have tried several attempts, but I don't know where i am going wrong with my code. I have properly assigned several attribites of my code, but i continue to get a syntax error with my code. I intend to return the amount of numbers in a user generated list, as well as the lowest and highest in the list, in addition to its sum and mean, and median. Specifically, I keep getting errors back when I try to print my last line.

```py
def average_ans(numbers):
    lowest = None
    highest = None
    total = 0
    numbers = []
    while True:
        try:
            line = input("enter a number or Enter to finish: ")
            if not line:
                break
            count=0
            while count<len(numbers):
                count+=1
            number = int(line)
            numbers+=number
            i=0
            while i<len(numbers):
                total=total+numbers[i]
            mean=int(total/count)
            lowest=min(numbers)
            highest=max(numbers)
            median=((highest-lowest)/2)+lowest
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
    if numbers=="":
        print("numbers:", numbers)
        print("count =", count)
        print("lowest =", lowest)
        print("highest =", highest)
        print("mean =", mean)
        print("median =", median)
```

Comment: `i continue to get a syntax error with my code` -- so please at least include the error text in your question.

Comment: the error is as follows: numbers+=number, Type Error, 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @BrandenKhushu So when you say `I keep getting errors back when I try to print my last line`, you actually mean `I get an exception halfway through my function`.

Comment: Yes, I was working with an earlier form of this function, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `+=` to add a number to the `numbers` list. (You could use it to add another iterable to the list.)

Instead of

```py
numbers += number
```

do

```py
numbers.append(number)
```

That aside, there are other non-Pythonisms I'd fix (and the definition of `median` seems iffy to me, but I didn't change it). This is how I'd write something like the above.

```py
def print_stats(numbers):
    count = len(numbers)
    total = sum(numbers)
    mean = int(total / count)
    lowest = min(numbers)
    highest = max(numbers)
    median = ((highest - lowest) / 2) + lowest
    print("numbers:", numbers)
    print("count =", count)
    print("lowest =", lowest)
    print("highest =", highest)
    print("mean =", mean)
    print("median =", median)


def average_ans(numbers):
    numbers = []
    while True:
        line = input("enter a number or Enter to finish: ")
        if not line:
            break
        numbers.append(int(line))
    if not numbers:
        return
    print_stats(numbers)
```

Comment: I used the apppend, but now the function doesn't loop.